# Limiting Access Permissions in the Backend

Tags: permissions, access

I have a user who I want to give access to only one component in the backend (com_joocommerce).

I have followed the steps suggested to me from many sources... like this one http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=749774 (first reply)

The thing is that this component does not have any permissions in its options screen.  And the alternative method of installing ACL Manager is not free.

How would I best go about managing the permissions for the component?

Answer (score 2):

Add a simple access.xml file in your administrator component directory (administrator/components/com_joocommerce) and you can configure permissions for your component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access component="com_joocommerce">
    <section name="component">
        <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.manage" title="JACTION_MANAGE" description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    </section>
</access>
```

Then in config.xml in the same directory add a new fieldset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <!-- your other stuff here... -->

    <fieldset name="permissions" label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL" description="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_DESC">
        <field name="rules" type="rules" label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL" class="inputbox" validate="rules" filter="rules" component="com_joocommerce" section="component"/>
    </fieldset>
</config>
```

Now you should be able to configure your access permissions for this component.